# SVN trunk,branches and tag folder creation

Tags: svn

I have a `SVN` server in linux, and Currently a project named “repos” is created and all new projects are added as sub-directories of “repos” project.
I create a new sub-directory with this command:

1. `mkdir Newproject`
2. `svn --username abc import NewProject http://192.168.0.86/repos/Newproject -m "Initial import".`
3. created a username
4. password for the user

Now I want to create a trunk, branches and tag folders under the Newproject folder.

Can any one help me with the code to create these folder.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "code". This is basic SVN command usage which is explained **very** well in the manual http://svnbook.org/

There's absolutely **nothing** special about these directories as far as Subversion is concerned - it's a naming convention. You could call `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` `Larry`, `Darryl` and `OtherBrotherDarryl` and SVN wouldn't care - what matters is that your *users* understand what they mean.

You can create your directories in two ways:

- `svn mkdir URL_TO_DIRECTORY`
- Check out the project, create the directories locally, `svn add` them, then `svn commit` them.